# Windows 7 - How to assign Macros to function keys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, macros

I am running Windows 7. I would like to assign macros to the function keys. For instance, I would like to have F10 open up chrome.

I googled on how to do this and what I found was to go to control panel -> keyboard and I should be able to configure the function keys. However, when I do this I see no option for that...only key repeat speed and driver.

How can I assign macros to the function keys in Windows 7?

Comment: This is going to be dependent on the keyboard and driver that you have on your computer; not all keyboards or keyboard drivers will support the functionality. The default Windows keyboard driver does not appear to support the functionality.

Comment: You may also want to look into [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), a general-purpose "macro" program.